# What are the best stars ranking system (libs) to implement on IOS 6 app?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, rank

I have [this](https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating) system, but I it's frame based, I want another solution with `views` or another kind to place on the exact position.
With frames it's hard to place the stars on the right places and handle them.
I want a system with 5 stars and with the possiblity to rate something with a half stars.

Comment: Do you know how frames relate to views?

Comment: Yes, I think so. `CGRectMake (x, y, width, height)` ?

Comment: That's how you create a CGRect...

Comment: So.. what's your point? I asked for a different system.

Comment: My point is you didn't answer my question, fueling my suspicion you don't know why you're looking for an alternative solution to what you already have.

Comment: It's simple, I don't want to give x and y coordinates to put something on a cell or a viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few I'm aware of:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsfavstarcontrol
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/edstarrating
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dyrateview

there are a few others as well out at cocoa controls - a great site btw.  take a look and do a search.

best of luck.

Comment: Can you take a look into the `DYrateView` and the one that I used, you think I can use mine to give the rank, save it like float on the DB (already implemented) and then use the `DYRateView` to display it?

Comment: Hi Fabio, I'd like to help, but you'll have to post the code your looking to fix or modify.